# How do you get the "@/" alias working in a Typescript ESM project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I'm trying to run my script using ESM:

```
ts-node --esm -r tsconfig-paths/register -T src/server/api/jobs/index.ts
```

However, it can't seem to handle my imports like `import '@/server/init.ts`:

```
CustomError: Cannot find package '@/server' imported from /Users/me/Sites/myapp/src/server/api/jobs/index.ts
```

I've tried adding this to my `tsconfig.json`:

```
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
```

I've also tried changing the "name" of my `package.json':

```
"name": "@/server",
```

My folder structure is:

```
/myapp
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
  /src
    /server
      /api
        /jobs
          index.ts
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "checkJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "ES5"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "types": ["node"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    ".eslintrc.cjs",
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "*.js",
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.cjs",
    "**/*.mjs",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "./src/*",
    "src/*"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
  // "ts-node": {
  //   "esm": true,
  //   "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node",
  //   "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  // }
}
```

Comment: Try `"@/*": ["/*"]` or `"@/*": ["./*"]`

Comment: I have a similar problem. Do you find a way to solve it ? During research, i found soluce with custom loader, or using tsx instead of ts-node etc...Did you try it ? Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Ts-node seems problemagical with ESM.

For my ESM project I didn't use it, but `tsx`. Lets first go through how I run the TS code (in dev):

> npm i --save-dev tsx

```
"main": "build/index.js",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
    ...
    "dev": "tsx watch ./src/index.ts",
    ...
```

Above first i setted the main file in the build folder, where we are building the production code. This can vary... dist/build/etc... Using module for ESM. Than with tsx we run with hot reload (watch) the index.ts entry file right under src.

Fyi, here is my tsconfig:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
    "display": "Node 20",
    "compilerOptions": {
        /* Specify what module code is generated. */
        "module": "NodeNext",
        /* Specify which ECMAScript version the project's output JavaScript code must support.*/
        "target": "ESNext",
        /*
         * Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier.
         * Bundler removes the need to specify the full path inside imports
         */
        "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
        /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        /* Removes comments from the project's output JavaScript code. */
        "removeComments": true,
        /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators which works with the module reflect-metadata. */
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        /* Enables experimental support for decorators, which is a version of decorators that predates the TC39 standardization process. */
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        /* When set, TypeScript will include the original content of the .ts file as an embedded string in the source map (using the source map’s sourcesContent property). This is often useful in the same cases as inlineSourceMap. */
        "inlineSources": true,
        /* Enables the generation of sourcemap files. */
        "sourceMap": true,
        /* Allow JavaScript files to be imported inside the project, instead of just .ts and .tsx files. */
        "allowJs": true,
        /* By default (with esModuleInterop false or not set) TypeScript treats CommonJS/AMD/UMD modules similar to ES6 modules. */
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        /* The strict flag enables a wide range of type checking behavior that results in stronger guarantees of program correctness. */
        "strict": true,
        /* When set to true, TypeScript will raise an error when a class property was declared but not set in the constructor. */
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        /* This flag controls how import works */
        "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",
        /* Specify the location where a debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of relative source locations */
        "sourceRoot": "/",
        /* The longest common path of all non-declaration input files. */
        "rootDir": "src",
        /* Directory name of the project's output JavaScript code. */
        "outDir": "build",
        /* Specify to generate .d.ts files for every TypeScript or JavaScript file inside the project. */
        "declaration": true,
        /* Sets a base directory from which to resolve non-relative module names. */
        "baseUrl": ".",
        /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the baseUrl if set, or to the tsconfig file itself otherwise. */
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*"]
        },
    },
    "exclude": ["coverage", "build"]
}
```

This aligns with your specs for running TS code from src.

If you intend to build code into JS into (for now lets say) build folder, and run that in prod:

First we need to set up a patch to the tsconfig.json, lets call it f ex tsconfig.prod.json:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*"]
        },
    }
}
```

Than we will need to build this code with tsc:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "rm -fr ./build && tsc",
    ....
```

This removes the build folder if exists, than builds it again with tsc.

Now lets run the built code:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "TS_NODE_PROJECT=./tsconfig.prod.json node .",
    ....
```

Please keep in mind, that with these path aliases, you will need to end your TS references with .js ending. It's not an issue technically, but in my personal opinion looks tremendously ugly. I am suffering for the last days to figure out a comprehensive path alias policy for my project, and have it running on dev and prod... Pls let me know what you think.